# How to create an array of instances of generic nested classes?

Tags: java, arrays

I try to create an array of instances of inner class objects, which are derived from generic inner classes.

When I do this

```
delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
```

I get the warnings:

```
Table.java:58: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Table.Column
    delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
                                   ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Table.Column<V>
  where V is a type-variable:
    V extends Object declared in class Table.Column
Table.java:58: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
    delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
                       ^
  required: Table.Column<Object>[]
  found:    Table.Column[]
2 warnings
```

And if I follow the requirement in the warning and do the following

```
delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column<Object>[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
```

I get the following errors:

```
Table.java:58: error: incompatible types: Delivery.Number cannot be converted to Table.Column<Object>
    delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column<Object>[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
                                                                ^
Table.java:58: error: incompatible types: Delivery.Date cannot be converted to Table.Column<Object>
    delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column<Object>[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
                                                                                        ^
Table.java:58: error: generic array creation
    delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column<Object>[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
                       ^
3 errors
```

How to solve this problem without warning and error?

This is the complete example:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.lang.System.err;

abstract class Table
{
  String           name = null;
  Column<Object>[] columns = null;

  abstract class Column<V>
  {
    String  name = null;
    Integer type = null;

    class Value
    {
      V value;

      Value (V value)
      {
        this.value = value;
      }
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
      return name + ": " + type.toString();
    }
  }

  public String toString ()
  {
    return this.name + " ("
      + Stream.of(columns).map (Column<Object>::toString).collect (Collectors.joining (", "))
      + ")";
  }
}

class Delivery extends Table
{
  { name = "Delivery"; }

  class Number extends Delivery.Column<String>
  {
    { name = "Number"; }
  }

  class Date extends Delivery.Column<String>
  {
    { name = "Date"; }
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    String[] strings;
    Delivery delivery = new Delivery ();
    delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column<Object>[] { delivery.new Number (), delivery.new Date () };
    err.println (delivery);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code `delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column<Object>[]` doesn't agree with the error message `delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column[]`, which clearly states that the type argument is missing. Which is correct?

Comment: `Column<Object>[] columns` a value can never (safely) be assigned to this because you can't create generic arrays. Use a `List<Column<Object>>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is a proper solution, it's more like a workaround using a `List<Column<?>>` container (as @Andy Turner suggested in the comments).
Then the list can be converted into array of columns if needed.

```java
    // abstract class Table
    protected List<Column<?>> columns;
    protected Column<?>[] arrColumns = null;

    public Column<?>[] getColumnsAsArray() {
        if (null == columns) {
            return null;
        }
        Column<?>[] arr = (Column<?>[]) Array.newInstance(Column.class, columns.size());
        return columns.toArray(arr);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name 
            + "\nlist: (" + columns.stream().map(Column::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + ")"
            + "\narr: (" + Stream.of(arrColumns).map(Column::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + ")";
    }
```

So, the list of columns can be created and converted to array as shown below:

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Delivery delivery = new Delivery();
    delivery.columns = Arrays.asList(delivery.new Number(), delivery.new Date());

    delivery.arrColumns = delivery.getColumnsAsArray();

    err.println(delivery);

    Arrays.stream(delivery.arrColumns)
          .map(Object::getClass)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}

class Delivery extends Table {
  { name = "Delivery"; }
 
  class Number extends Table.Column<Number> {
    { name = "Number"; type = 1; }  // define _type_ to prevent NPE in Column<V>::toString
  }
 
  class Date extends Table.Column<String> {
    { name = "Date"; type = 10; } // define _type_ to prevent NPE
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
# stderr
Delivery
list: (Number: 1, Date: 10)
arr: (Number: 1, Date: 10)

# stdout
class Delivery$Number
class Delivery$Date
```

[Online demo (updated)](https://ideone.com/jnavay)

*Verified with compiler option `-Xlint:all`*

Comment: You need to compile with `javac -Xlint:all` to see the warnings.

Comment: @ceving, Sorry, I assumed this option is enabled by default.  I updated the answer, and now the compiler does not display any warnings.

Comment: With this approach, I think you don't need to define `getColumnsAsArray()`. You can just change the assignment as `delivery.columns = new Delivery.Column[]{delivery.new Number(), delivery.new Date()};`

Comment: @HiteshA.Bosamiya, such implementation causes an unwanted compiler warning, this case is described in the beginning of the post.